# Is there a contradiction about the definition of full-expression

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

The definition of full-expression is said as following:
[intro.execution#12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.execution#12)

> A full-expression is
>
> > - an unevaluated operand,
> > - a constant-expression,
> > - an init-declarator or a mem-initializer, including the constituent expressions of the initializer,
> > - an invocation of a destructor generated at the end of the lifetime of an object other than a temporary object, or
> > - an expression that is **not a subexpression** of another expression and that is **not otherwise part of a full-expression**.

Consider the following code:

```cpp
0+1;
```

The definition says `constant-expression` is a full-expression, Due to within the expression `0+1`, thereof `0` and `1` are both constant-expression, hence they are all `full-expression`, However The last bullet says `an expression that is not a subexpression of another expression` is a full-expression. But whether the operand `0` or `1`, they are all subexpression of the expression `0+1` and the expression `0+1` is a full-expression. Moreover `0` and `1` is also a part of that full-expression. That means sometimes, the second bullet will contradict with the last bullet. How to interpret this. Is it a contradiction about the full-expression' definition?

When take the expression `0+1` as an initializer. It seems to be a part of full-expression, because of this rule:

> For an initializer, performing the initialization of the entity (including evaluating default member initializers of an aggregate) is also considered **part of the full-expression**.

The expression `0+1` itself is a constant-expression, So it's countered as a full-expression. However when it is taken as an initializer, It's a part of the full-expression, So whether the constant-expression `0+1` is a full-expression or not in this case?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218251/discussion-on-question-by-jack-x-is-there-a-contradiction-about-the-definition-o).

Answer (score 2):

See the word "**or**" at the end of the fourth bullet point. It's supposed to apply to the whole list, i.e. an expression is a full-expression if it matches one or more of the bullets.

The case `0+1` matches the second bullet , so it is a full-expression.  It does not match any of the other bullets but that's not a problem.

Comment: Ok. So when an initializer is itself a constant-expression, and It has a constructor ,within the constructor, there is a `mem-initializer`. So when the rule says the full-expression of initialization, which the full-expression the sentence refers to?

Comment: @jackX that would be a new question, not a comment

Comment: Please interpret this example, `struct S {   S(int i): I(i) { } int I;};  S s1(1); ` The full-expression is call of S​::​S(int) due to the last bullet, and the initialization of I is a full-expression due to bullet 3, So which is the full-expression of instantiation for s1?

Comment: I think they are a same question. Because the full-expression is not a part of another full-expression. It sounds like a contradiction.

Comment: @jackX it's not the same question . This question is about whether or not some particular construct is a full-expression, whereas the question you ask in comments is about which of the full-expressions in the construct is meant by "the full-expression of initialization"

Comment: This question is about when the one bullet is satisfied individually, however the satisfied bullet will contradict with any other bullet, In this case, It is a full-expression or the definition is contradict-itself. So my question in the comment is a specialization of the question.

Comment: @jackX there is no contradiction, the bullets are not meant to be simultaneous or exclusive. They are all to be considered independently of each other . The word "or" in English language (and in C programming) means that only one bullet must be satisfied for the condition to be true . You seem to be trying to satisfy bullet 2 and bullet 5 at once for some reason .

Comment: so you mean `S::S(int)` is a full-expression and `I(i)` is also a full-expression, they are all full-expression?

Comment: @jackX I will not be responding to any further of your comments that ask new questions in comments

Comment: I open a new question. Looking forward to your interpretation. Thanks.

Comment: @jackX thanks although I have no idea about the answer to the other question, the bit about "full expression of initialization" never made any sense to me . Hopefully someone else will answer

Comment: Thanks. So for this question, you mean that as long as an expression or some stuff satisfies one condition of the list, then it will be considered as a full-expression, regardless whether they violate any other condition of the list, Right? Even though violate `For an initializer, performing the initialization of the entity (including evaluating default member initializers of an aggregate) is also considered part of the full-expression.`? Such as `0` is taken as an initializer .

Answer (score 0):

The definition of a full-expression is talking about the *context* of where the expression appears, not about the *form* of the expression.  So while something like `0+1` is a constant expression in *form*, if the *context* in which it appears is not a constant-expression context, then this bullet point does not apply.

What this bullet point is really saying is that anywhere in the grammer the term *constant-expression* appears on the right side of a grammar rule, that context is a full-expression context, and counts as a full expression.

Comment: You haven't interpret when the case violate the last rule.

Comment: @jackX: there's nothing to interpret - the last bullet point is also talking about context; just a completely different and unrelated set of contexts.  If `0+1;` is a expression-statement, then it `0+1` would be a full expression by that last bullet point.

Comment: For example `int a = 0+1;` The expression `0+1` is a full-expression , `0` and `1` are still full-expression?

Comment: In that case, `a = 0+1` is a full expression because of bullet point 3 (it's an init-declarator), and `0+1` and `0` and `1` are not, as they don't match any of the contexts in any of the bullet points.  Note that while `0+1` is "not a subexpresion of another expression" it is "otherwise part of a full expression"

Comment: I don't understand why `0` and `1` are not. `0` and `1` are both constant-expression, It should satisfy the bullet 2. why not a full-expression? `0+1` is also a constant-expression too.

Comment: Because they're in a context where any expression is valid, not just a constant expression.

Comment: The definition is `A full-expression is a constant-expression`, `0` is a constant-expression, `1` is also, moreover `0+1` is also constant-expression, they all satisfy the condition `a constant-expression`.

Comment: Please interpret this example, struct S {   S(int i): I(i) { } int I;};  S s1(1);  The full-expression is call of S​::​S(int) due to the last bullet, and the initialization of I is a full-expression due to bullet 3, So which is the full-expression of instantiation for s1? How to understand the wording